# Multiple Flask apps in cPanel - change

Tags: python, flask, passenger, wsgi

I am having difficulties setting up a second flask app in cpanel - this is due to the same resource being used (port in flask).

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. One main app `domain.com`
2. One second separate app on `subdomain.domain.com`

The first part is done and flask is running on Phusion Passenger WSGI successfully.
I am now looking for a way to pass a different port for flask in my second app and have tried using an environment variable:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
```

Even though I passed this variable in my virtualenv for the second app, the conflict persists. 
Is there any other way to define the port for flask?

Thanks for reading & regards!

Answer (score 0):

If both apps have different names and directories, then there should not a problem. Using sub-domains, I deployed three different apps which were using same Database. Here is the deployment which is quite simple,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RKN3kVKCG4&t=0m21s